# datepicker in grid using vfp 9.0

Tags: sql-server-2012, visual-foxpro

my working project is on visual fox-pro 9.0 ,
so i need design form in that, i am adding grid with following 2 columns, 1st column is text-box control and 2nd column is date-picker control

following steps i did it:

1. i created new form
2. added grid control
3. added active x Microsoft date-picker control 6.0

but here is my problem,

1. on focus only its showing date-picker but i want to show all the time when i open the form.
2. changing row date affecting other row date also.
3. with null or empty column means needs show blank.

please help me,I'm tried to searching how date-picker works in grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually do a slight alternative to what you are proposing.  I would take the default grid textbox control and allow it to always show the given "Value" existing, null, whatever.  Then, in the double-click event of the textbox of the column have it call a stand-alone form that has the date-picker control, allow user to change date, and store it upon return (if so chosen).

Otherwise, to properly show the calendar control you'll probably need to have a very large row-height, and change the grid columns "SPARSE" property to FALSE (show every time).